# NetOffice and VSTO is it possible the coexistence?

Tags: excel, vsto, netoffice

I created a projects for an add-ins in excel using ribbon designer and i am planning do to some changes. However, to work with excel.interop is really tricky.

So, i wish to know if it is possible to coexist Netoffice and VSTO?.

AFAIK, what i am missing is the way to obtain the current application

in NetOffice:

```
var application= new Excel.Application(???, ????);
```

while in VSTO i use:

```
var application=Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
```

Comment: [ie?](http://xldennis.wordpress.com/2007/11/25/access-running-instances-of-excel-in-vb/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalent for `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application` in Netoffice is `this.Application`
There are some samples with the NetOffice source code to help.